# Cannot import Module from Module

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module that imports a module. But that doesnt work. This is my folder hierarchy:

```
/Project/
-test.py
     /recognizer/
     -__init__.py
     -tools.py
     -feature_extraction.py
```

I am importing `tools.py` inside of `feature_extraction.py`. If I run the `feature_extraction.py` it all works like it should. Now I want to import the `feature_extraction.py` from the `test.py`, but that doesnt work. I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'`.

Inside the `test.py` I am importing like this `from recognizer import feature_extraction` that works like it should I think. Inside of `feature_extraction.py` I am importing just like this `import tools`. This should work I think, but it doesnt.

Comment: try to import tools like this `from . import tools`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this way.

```
from . import tools
```

If you `import tools` from `feature_extraction.py` file. it will lookup main directory which `test.py` lays.

Answer (score 0):

try to import in feature_extraction tools like this:
import recognizer.tools